# Transferring ownership of an IDisposable object and the builder design pattern

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I'm used to the approach when it is the object that creates another object (either directly or through factories, builders, etc) - is the one that "owns" it, thus manages its lifetime.

This idea works fine in almost every case.

But sometimes the one that creates an object simply cannot manage it, for instance in the builder design pattern implementation:

```
IFoo BuildFoo()
{
    var dep = new Dep();

    return new Foo(dep);
}
```

So, here the builder cannot manage the lifetime of the `dep` object since:

1. it does not have a reference to it;
2. it does not know when it is safe to `Dispose` it.

The naive solution would be to make `Foo : IDisposable` and let it manage the `Dep` passed to its constructor.

But then another dilemma arises:

```
using (var dep = new Dep())
{
    using (var foo = new Foo(dep))
    {
        // (1) do something with foo
    }

    // (2) !!! do something with dep !!!
}
```

The code above becomes unsafe: at the point `(2)` it's not safe to use `dep` since it is already `Dispose`d by `foo`.

And there is nothing syntactically that can denote, whose responsibility it is to manage the lifetime of an object.

So the question: what would be a general solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I wouldn't worry about it. I'm going to get shot to pieces here, I imagine, but "builders", "factories" etc are all places where I think it's okay to create an object and hand off it's disposal to the thing that asked for it.

There is a rule though that the builder/factory must *only* be *creating* the object, and not doing anything with it.

Of course, if you're newing-up objects using the `new` keyword, then you're coupling yourself to that implementation (even if it's indirectly via a factory class). You might want instead to consider dependency injection, depending on what the created objects are for, in which case a DI container would create the objects *and* dispose them for you at the correct time, based on their configured lifestyle.

Comment: Right, but then see the snippet #2. When an object is created outside of one of those creational patterns (which is perfectly legit) then there is no contract that would hint us that we're transferring ownership of whatever we pass into its constructor.

Comment: Erm, don't. Be consistent. You should only have factories for objects that are difficult in themselves to create (needs complex initialisation etc). If they are, then have the factory *and use the factory*. There is huge value in consistency.

Comment: The builder *helps* to construct a complicated object (usually with some runtime conditions), but its purpose is purely auxiliary. That slightly contradicts with factories that are specifically designed to encapsulate *the only way* to construct an object. So I don't think it is inconsistent to use both builders and constructors directly.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that for any object that is sufficiently complex that a builder is needed, have the builder and use the builder. Either way, the code that receives the object is responsible for it's disposable. Think of builders and factories like the `new` keyword - they're just hiding all the dependencies you'd have to pass in. And I'll mention DI once more because I think if you're in this territory it's a valid consideration.

Comment: "because I think if you're in this territory it's a valid consideration." --- it's not a practical problem actually, but more a research on what idioms/tools there are to denote an ownership transfer. Eg: in Rust language it is explicit, so my aim here is to find out whether there are any practices in .net/c# about that.

Comment: Fair enough. The idiom is "if you create an object, you're responsible for disposing of it". In practice, "create an object" includes using a builder or a factory, which is little more than a `new` statement anyway. DI containers just go a step further.

Answer (score 1):

very naive implementation

```
void Main()
{
    using (var builder = new Builder())
    {
        var foo = builder.Create();
        // do smtg
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Dep instance)
    {
    }
}

public class Dep : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} disposed!");
    }
}

public class Builder : IDisposable
{
    private List<IDisposable> _disposables = new List<System.IDisposable>();

    public Foo Create()
    {
        var dep = new Dep();
        _disposables.Add(dep);

        var foo = new Foo(dep);
        return foo;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach(var d in _disposables)
            d.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} disposed!");
    }
}
```

If something owns IDisposable, then it should implement IDisposable. 
And, ofcourse, this is very naive impl, just as sample.

Comment: Yep, this looks more interesting. Is there an idiom that states that "whatever is produced by `IDisposable` object is not safe to use after its disposal"?

Comment: Yep. I read about this many times,, but now can only remember book "Framework design guidelines". This book will be interesting for you, I think.

Comment: Also, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've read it, it does not have anything relevant: the problem is more about design.

Comment: You should to ask, who owns of Dep instance? If Builder - it should implement IDisposable. If only Foo - Foo should implement it. For example, if you are using StreamWriter - its get Stream as parameter and then its responsible to close/dispose stream.

Comment: that's what my very question: what is more idiomatic. Since I can think of cases when `Dep` is owned by either `Foo` or by some outer scope.

Comment: If you are askiing exatly about Builder pattern, not sure that there are answer for you. Disposing behaviour sould be configurable for builder. For example, if you are using DI container, you can choose which instances will be container-controlled and which - controlled externally.

Comment: >>that's what my very question
There are no certain answer, because it depends of situation in project. What Dep means? If Dep - somthing like stream - it should be disposed by Foo, because you probably dont want to use it twice. But if it something like EventAggregator or DbTransaction  - it should NOT be disposed by Foo.

Answer (score 0):

What about you let `Foo` call the builder to instantiate `Dep` and use it whenever it needs to. This way `Foo` manages the lifetime of `Dep` without the client of `Foo` having to worry about it.

Comment: Then `Foo` would know about the builder. The whole idea of the inversion of control is that you're fed with dependencies. And the whole thing becomes harder to test.

Comment: So, why did you then assume that the client of Foo would need to manage the lifetime of Dep. Why don't you let Foo dispose Dep when it disposes itself.

Comment: Because there is no explicit contract that states that after `Foo` disposed its dependencies are also in the invalid state.

Comment: So, then let the builder manage the lifetime of Dep, see @tym32167 answer